# How do I deserialize NuGet.NuGetVersion into a class in C#?

Tags: c#, json, nuget, deserialization, system.text.json

I'm a beginner, just writing code for an application for my work and I was trying to deserialize a class, but encountered an error.
I have a class named Nuget, that looks like this:

```cs
public class Nuget
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Id { get; set; }
    public NuGetVersion Version { get; set; }
    public string? PackageSource { get; set; }
    public System.DateTimeOffset BlobCreation { get; set; }
}
```

Now I'm using .Net 6, with System.Text.Json in the method that tries to deserialize a file.
When I try to do it I receive the following error message:

> Encountered exception:
>
> System.NotSupportedException: Deserialization of types without a parameterless constructor, a singular parameterized constructor, or a parameterized
> constructor annotated with 'JsonConstructorAttribute' is not supported. Type 'NuGet.Versioning.NuGetVersion'. Path: $.Version | LineNumber: 0 |
> BytePositionInLine: 65..

Why would NuGetVersion need any constuctor?

The deserializer method is just your usual code.

```cs
try
{
    Nuget? deserializedObject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Nuget>(DirectoryManager.ReadResourceFromExternal(filePath));
    if (deserializedObject is null) throw new ArgumentNullException("deserializedObject");

    return deserializedObject;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    LogManager.CatchLog(ex, new string[] {
    $"Loading the requested file of {filePath } is not possible\n",
    "Please check the filepath"
});
}
```

The ReadResourceFromExternal method returns the decrypted file in a string format.

```
public static string ReadResourceFromExternal(string filePath) {
    using Stream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer: DAPIManager.Decrypt(filePath));
    using StreamReader reader = new(stream);
    return reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

So far, I'm just trying to understand why NuGet.Version is not acceptable, since it has a {get;set;}, isn't this a parameterless constructor?

I was pondering if I should just have a string instead and convert the NuGet.Version manually.

Or am I misunderstanding the issue here?

Comment: What the ouput you get from DirectoryManager.ReadResourceFromExternal(filePath)? you have to post it.

Comment: Added it, thanks for mentioning that.

Comment: Thanks, but we need a text of the file

Comment: Well, the System.Text.Jso deserialization code somehow has to create the NugetVersion object, but has no idea how to do this without help of a JsonConstructorAttribute. The easiest way out would indeed be to declare it as `string` in your class and call `NugetVersion.Parse` later yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not with the `Nuget.Version` property, it is with the **`NuGetVersion` type itself.** [`NuGet.Versioning.NuGetVersion`](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/b84ca7373557c5725836697f81786ed22e20ead5/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Versioning/NuGetVersion.cs) is an immutable type that has multiple parameterized constructors but no parameterless constructor, so System.Text.Json cannot figure out how to construct it when deserializing the value of `Nuget.Version`.

So, what are your options?

**Firstly**, Microsoft's own [NuGet.Protocol](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Protocol) package has a complete set of [Newtonsoft.Json converters](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/tree/3c5cea96aa281d0703d7334d16be14fe8a7e0918/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Protocol/Converters) for serializing and deserializing NuGet types so you could just install that package and use Newtonsoft:

```
var nuget = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Nuget>(json, 
    NuGet.Protocol.JsonExtensions.ObjectSerializationSettings);
```

Or even more simply:

```
var nuget = NuGet.Protocol.JsonExtensions.FromJson<Nuget>(json);
```

**Secondly**, if you would prefer to stick with System.Text.Json, you will need to port any required converters and settings used in [`NuGet.Protocol.JsonExtensions`](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/3c5cea96aa281d0703d7334d16be14fe8a7e0918/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Protocol/Converters/JsonExtensions.cs) from Newtonsoft.

Create the following converters:

```
public class NuGetVersionConverter : System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter<NuGetVersion>
{
    public override NuGetVersion? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) => 
        NuGetVersion.Parse(reader.GetString());
    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, NuGetVersion value, JsonSerializerOptions options) => 
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString());
}

public class VersionRangeConverter : System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter<VersionRange>
{
    public override VersionRange? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) => 
        VersionRange.Parse(reader.GetString());
    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, VersionRange value, JsonSerializerOptions options) => 
        // ToString()->Parse()->ToString() adapted from https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/f24bad0668193ce21a1db8cabd1ce95ba509c7f0/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Protocol/Converters/VersionRangeConverter.cs#L41
        // Though in all honesty I'm not sure why the round-trip is necessary.
        writer.WriteStringValue((VersionRange.Parse(value.ToString())).ToString());
}

// TODO: 
// VersionInfoConverter, https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/3c5cea96aa281d0703d7334d16be14fe8a7e0918/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Protocol/Converters/VersionInfoConverter.cs
// FingerprintsConverter, https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/f24bad0668193ce21a1db8cabd1ce95ba509c7f0/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Protocol/Converters/FingerprintsConverter.cs
```

Then serialize and deserialize using the following options:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Converters = { new NuGetVersionConverter(), new VersionRangeConverter(), new JsonStringEnumConverter(JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase) },
    DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull,
    // Other options as required
    WriteIndented = true,
};

var nuget = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Nuget>(json, options);
```

Notes:

- The Newtonsoft converters serialize `NuGetVersion` as a string, so my converter does also:

  ```
  "Version": "6.0.3-rc.1",
  ```
- The Json.NET settings used by NuGet.Protocol can be seen [here](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/3c5cea96aa281d0703d7334d16be14fe8a7e0918/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Protocol/Converters/JsonExtensions.cs#L18):

  > ```
  > public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings ObjectSerializationSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
  > {
  >     MaxDepth = JsonSerializationMaxDepth,
  >     NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
  >     TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None,
  >     Converters = new List<JsonConverter>
  >     {
  >         new NuGetVersionConverter(),
  >         new VersionInfoConverter(),
  >         new StringEnumConverter { NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy() },
  >         new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal },
  >         new FingerprintsConverter(),
  >         new VersionRangeConverter()
  >    },
  > };
  > ```

  The Newtonsoft settings use camel case for enums, so the equivalent System.Text.Json options probably should as well.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qofyaF).